# Nested views in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working with some nested states in angularjs and everything goes well till a part of the URL is dynamic.

This works well

```
.state('company', {
            url: "/company",
            templateUrl: 'views/company/index.html'
        })
        .state('company.list', {
            url: "/",
            views: {
                "c_list": {
                  templateUrl: 'views/company/list.html',
                  controller: 'CompanyCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('company.view', {
            url: "/:company_id",
            views: {
                "c_info": {
                  templateUrl: 'views/company/view.html',
                  controller: 'CompanyCtrl'
                },
                "c_menu": {
                  templateUrl: 'views/company/menu.html',
                  controller: 'MenuCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

But when it comes to extend the company.view, as it has a dynamic parameter, it fails.

```
.state('company.view.user', {
            url: "/user",
            views: {
              "c_nested":{
                templateUrl: 'views/user/index.html',
              }
            }
        })
        .state('company.view.user.list', {
            url: "/",
            views: {
                "u_list": {
                  templateUrl: 'views/user/list.html',
                  controller: 'UserCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

If I extend user from company instead of company.view the nested views are shown but if I extend from company.view only the main content is shown, not the nested one.

For company/index.html I've got:

```
<div ui-view="c_list"></div>
<div ui-view="c_info"></div>
<div ui-view="c_menu"></div>
<div ui-view="c_nested"></div>
```

For user/index.html I've got:

```
<div ui-view="u_list"></div>
<div ui-view="u_info"></div>
<div ui-view="u_menu"></div>
<div ui-view="u_nested"></div>
```

Presume all other html are as simple as

```
<div>hi</div>
```

The URLs I use are:

/company [works]

/company/92 [works]

/company/92/user [no way]

What should I do to make this work with dynamic params?

Comment: You need to provide outline of you html which contains these UI views. Also what urls are you hitting.

Comment: The second route defined with url "/" does not make sense, i think `/company` and `/company/` are the same. Also the user view would be defined in `views/company/view.html`? You have not provided info about that

Comment: I need those 'faux states' to append the template for company and user. They act as abstract states. In fact that part works. What doesn't work is after the /:company_id

Comment: The view for state `company.view.user` should be defined in `views/company/view.html` not in company/index. Can you check

Comment: No, it's not that. I have the container for everything in user put in `views/user/index.html` and that goes inserted in `c_nested`. I've tested moving /:company_id from parent to child and then it works. If anything else I'll end up doing it that way

Comment: If you solved this, post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have not solved this but came around it:

```
.state('company.user.view', {
  url: '/{user_id:[0-9]{1,8}}',
  ...
})
.state('company.user.edit', {
  url: '/{user_id:[0-9]{1,8}}/edit',
  ...
})
```

I have to specify an id in every single url